How can I get objects by foreign key without JOIN statement?
I have 2 classes:
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Description { get; set; } = default!;
    public IEnumerable<Comment>? Comments { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Content { get; set; } = default!;
    public Post Post { get; set; } = default!;
}

I added both to a DbContext and seed them like this:
Comment[] comments = new Comment[30];

for (int i = 0; i < comments.Length; i++)
{
    comments[i] = new() { Content = $"Comment {i}" };
}

context.Posts.AddRange(
    new() { Description = "Description1", Comments = comments },
    new() { Description = "Description2" },
    new() { Description = "Description3" }
);

context.SaveChanges();

Further I have some program logic where I want to retrieve all comments belonging to a post with a certain ID (I don't need the post itself). How would I implement this?
I have tried:
var a = await _dbContext.Comments
                        .Where(c => c.Post.Id == id)
                        .ToListAsync();

and
var a = await _dbContext.Comments
                        .Where(c => c.Post == new Post() { Id = id} )
                        .ToListAsync();

But both result in EF Core executing the SQL with an unnecessary join, which I don't want. Is there a way to get what I want?

Have you tried ForeignKey annotation? In Comment class add public long PostFK and annotate Post field with ForeignKey[("PostFK")]

It's not an "unnecessary" join, and joins are an integral part of how relational databases work. If the FKs are set up & indexed properly it's not going to result in anything like a table scan nor is EF going to do something like fetch the Post just because you reference it in a Where() condition.
There is absolutely nothing wrong with:
var a = await _dbContext.Comments
    .Where(c => c.Post.Id == id)
    .ToListAsync();

Though you do have the option to use explicit FK properties in your entities:
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Content { get; set; } = default!;
    public int PostId { get; set; } = default!;
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PostId))]
    public Post Post { get; set; } = default!;
}

Here you could then write the query as:
var a = await _dbContext.Comments
    .Where(c => c.PostId == id)
    .ToListAsync();

However, I generally recommend when it comes to using navigation properties to use the shadow FK (where the PostId is not declared/exposed in the entity) as when you have FKs exposed, your entities have two sources of truth for what the Post ID actually is. comment.PostId and comment.Post.Id. In cases where you could move a comment from one post to another, setting the PostId would work in cases where the Post reference isn't eager loaded/resolved, but you can run into issues where code checks one vs. the other and changes haven't been persisted. I don't believe EF will reload the Post navigation property automatically when you save the entity with a new PostId. I believe the reference will be updated if the new Post entity happens to already be tracked by the DbContext. This behaviour may have changed in EF core, but EF6 certainly had behaviour that could be unexpected in situations where updates were made via FK based on the state of navigation properties. I recommend an either-or between navigation property or FK property.
